# Find the distance between two towers/building

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

Mr Gray stood on top of the CN tower and spotted a Casa lama, his angle of depression is 6 degrees. He then turned around 110 degree and  found CNE. His angle of depression to CNE is about 9 degree. The height of CN tower is 553 m above the ground. Calculate the distance between casa lama and CNE.

I Know how to measure angle of depression and that this question would consists of 2 triangles but I am confused how to use that 110 degree in calculation. What is that angle??
Please help me with this question and I really prefer if somebody draw a proper triangle and locate that 110 degree

Comment: This seems underspecified. You have two rays $110^{\circ}$ apart and each points downward at some angle. Why can't we have multiple buildings along each ray? Wouldn't that affect their distance from each other?

Comment: What is the CN tower ? What is a casa lama ? A peruvian lama barn ?

Comment: I found by myself that the reference is Toronto town and that your "a Casa lama" is in fact "the Casa Loma" with an "o" instead of an "a". Be nice, next time: consider that people who ask context questions **deserve to be answered**. Besides, who is Mr Gray ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to make sense if both CNE and Casa lama are on the ground, which is not at all clear from the question. If this is not the case, then you need some piece of extra data to solve the exercise. Anyway, here is my attempt, assuming that those two things are on the ground. Rather than two triangles you should think of this as a pyramid, with triangular basis. Mr Gray is the top vertex of the pyramid, the other vertices are the base of the tower, CNE and the lama.

I tried to draw a picture explaining the situation, let me know if you find this helpful.[image]

Comment: I understand the figure but how can we apply the cosine rule, sine rule or trigonometric ratio there??? This question is part of grade 10 and I haven't studied pyramids yet

Comment: @TalhaAhmed the top of CN, the base of CN and CNE form a right triangle, so you can compute the distance between CNE and the base of CN. Similarly you compute the distance between the base of CN and lama. At this point you can obtain the distance between CNE and lama using the cosine rule.

Comment: Thank you so much. It makes sense now